# PsExec Access is denied

Tags: windows-7, runas, psexec

I am using `psexec.exe` to run programs in a different security context. However the programs start but it does not seem to be running in the specified security context.

In its minimal form:

```
psexec -u wsadmin -p password cmd
```

Starts a new cmd window if I type in that window `whoami`

```
C:\Windows\system32>whoami
win-k1r7g38nlkt\wsadmin

C:\Windows\system32>net localgroup administrators
Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
wsadmin
The command completed successfully.
```

As you can see I am definately the other user. And I can confirm that this user is member of the "Administrators group"

```
C:\Windows\system32>mkdir test
Access is denied.
```

If I use runas with the specified user it works as supposed. But I need to supply the password on the commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:

Turns out that when you have UAC enabled psexec does not work as supposed.
Whenever `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA` is set to `0` psexec works as expected.

Comment: The other way around this that doesn't require changing the registry is to just add the `-h` flag to the `psexec` command. This tells it to run the command with the elevated token, which is equivalent to launching a process "as administrator" from the context menu.

Comment: Setting `EnableLUA` to `0` disables `Admin Approval Mode`, which is basically the core of UAC. As a result the UAC will get disabled. [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772207%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: For me the -h flag did not work and disabling UAC was troubling, but I found a [better alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828432/psexec-access-denied-errors)

Comment: do i have to do this for **from** where I am running psexec(host) or for the target (remote) that will have the execution ?

Answer (score 12):

On Windows Vista and later, if UAC is enabled, a process launched by `psexec` -- even when run from an administrator account -- must have its elevate token set in order to get full privileges. This can be done by passing the `-h` attribute in the `psexec` command line. So, you would change your command to:

```
psexec -h -u wsadmin -p password cmd
```

For more info, run `psexec /?`:

```
    -h    If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process
          run with the account's elevated token, if available.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me "Couldn't install PSExec service access is denied"

Comment: Are you also running the initial command from an elevated command prompt, or are you using it as a local run-as?

Comment: The original command runs a 'user' security context. I can not use run-as for specific reasons.

Comment: Use "Elevated command prompt" or "Elevated PowerShell prompt" via "Start > Type "PowerShell" > Right-click "Windows PowerShell" > Select "Run as Administrator" then run the psexec command including the `-h` option.

Comment: @Underverse, Is it possible to use psexec from user CMD, not from admin PS? I wanna use psexec exactly for transition CMD into admin context :)

Comment: @Suncatcher The only difference should be to use `/` instead of `-` for switches for CMD prompt to call psexec. `psexec.exe /u "username" /p "password" /accepteula /i /h "c:\\Windows\System32\\cmd.exe"` in a CMD prompt vs `psexec.exe -u "username" -p "password" /accepteula -i -h PowerShell.exe  -NoExit` in PowerShell. In both cases the CMD/PowerShell window must be run as administrator.  Otherwise the `Couldn't install PsExec service:` message is thrown.

Comment: Bad (( I saw this as answer to question "how to elevate CMD".

Answer (score 6):

It took me hours to find a working way to `PsExec` between two Windows 7 Computers with non-Admin user starting `PsExec` ... Disabling UAC (`EnableLUA=0`, `ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin=0`, `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy=1`) did not work, turning off the Firewalls did not work...

Here I found the working way - thanks JelmerS:
(Info from [PSexec is not connecting to machine using supplied username and password](https://serverfault.com/questions/489822/psexec-is-not-connecting-to-machine-using-supplied-username-and-password/489845))

This is because `psexec` still tries to access the `ADMIN$` share with your local credentials, before executing your command as another user. According to this thread, you can cache credentials before executing psexec:

```
cmdkey.exe /add:MACHINE_NAME_HERE /user:MACHINE_NAME_HERE\Administrator /pass:PASSWORD_HERE 
psexec.exe \\MACHINE_NAME_HERE -i notepad
cmdkey.exe /delete:MACHINE_NAME_HERE
```

Comment: Note - If you don't want your password in the command line history, you can just use /pass with no password, and you will get a prompt to enter one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me, it doesn't get rid of UAC completely but turns it off for administrators

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\User Account Control:Run All Administrators in Admin Approval Mode - Disabled

Comment: Which isn't really a great idea. In addition how is this an improvement in comparison to the other available solutions?