# High System process CPU usage (Queue/Dequeue+TrimAlllSystemPagableMemory)

Tags: performance, windows-8.1, cpu-usage

I have ASUS G75VX laptop with latest Windows 8.1 (not Pro), all updates installed.

Task manager says it's the System process that takes my entire single CPU. When this high single CPU saturation happens it remains in such state until I restart the computer.

I used Process Hacker to get stack trace of the locked-in thread of System process:

```
0, ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x2786
1, ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x4133
2, ntoskrnl.exe!RtlTraceDatabaseValidate+0xb82
3, ntoskrnl.exe!RtlTraceDatabaseValidate+0x12cc
4, ntoskrnl.exe!RtlTraceDatabaseValidate+0xa4a
5, ntoskrnl.exe!MmTrimAllSystemPagableMemory+0xcf42
6, ntoskrnl.exe!MmTrimAllSystemPagableMemory+0xa019
7, ntoskrnl.exe!MmCreateMirror+0x56da
8, ntoskrnl.exe!MmTrimAllSystemPagableMemory+0xceba
9, ntoskrnl.exe!MmCreateMirror+0x6740
10, ntoskrnl.exe!RtlSidHashLookup+0x228f
11, ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc+0x1a4
12, ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x59d6
```

It is very hard to estimate when it happens, but it is very annoying and renders computer useless. I guess it happens usually 5 minutes after I have taken my laptop out of sleep, but that's just a guess.

I gathered some information via Windows Performance Recorder, the link is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/znwwh4a09hxas81/Foundation.7z

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Are you sure it is `System` process or `System Idle Process`? (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I am sure it's System process. You can check in ETL log, and also based on the fact that stack trace is there

Comment: possible duplicate of [High CPU usage by the "system" process](http://superuser.com/questions/527401/high-cpu-usage-by-the-system-process)

Comment: it is not duplicate, behavior is different

Comment: However, check [this](http://superuser.com/a/527557/180465) answer.
If it's a driver problem, then you will see that driver. In that case updating driver can solve the problem.
Also it can be virus activity. Scan your computer for viruses.

Comment: I checked the other answer, and I applied what it recommends already, before asking the question. I also have scanned my computer numerously for viruses. WPA doesn't narrow down this to any driver. I think system is malfunctioning, but what I need is some Win expert to take a look at ETL file, not guess around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high CPU usage comes from `ntoskrnl.exe!RtlScrubMemory` I asked Microsoft about this a wile ago and they told me this does RAM checks. It calls `ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker` to write some random data to the RAM.

[image]

You can't really fix it, because it is by design.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I applied the fix you mentioned as answer to https://superuser.com/questions/635837/high-cpu-load-from-system-when-idle, and I'd wait for a while to see if my problem is solved. I really don't understand why is this feature added.

Comment: By the way, if you can (with your credentials) modify "duplicate" tag to point to the question you were answering to (not as Jet did to a wrong one via "duplicate of" feature) so the next following person doesn't got down a rabbit hole, even better.