# Automatic Maintenance Significantly Slows Down Computer

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, performance, windows-8.1, automatic-maintenance

#### Problem

I've found on several occasions that I've gone to use my computer only to find that it's practically unusable; just about everything runs extremely slowly.

#### Symptoms

- The action center flag in the notification area showed that maintenance was being performed ("Maintenance in Progress") or a scheduled scan was running ("Scheduled Scan").
- The computer's HDD activity light was constantly on, indicating that the bottleneck could be the HDD activity.
- Opening Task Manager showed that "System" was using the HDD a lot (~20MB/s).
- Looking at the maintenance tasks in Task Scheduler shows that either "Idle Maintenance" or "Maintenance Configurator" (or both) triggered the maintenance.

#### What I've tried unsuccessfully

- Telling Windows to stop maintenance/scan. The problem still persists until I wait a long time for it to finish what it's doing.

Comment: The type of behavior you describe indicates a hardware problem.  The Automatic Maintenance should not cause your system to be unable to do anything else.

Comment: @Ramhound, in my experience, it's normal for Windows to be almost unusable if a process hogs a key resource such as the HDD or CPU, so I doubt it's a hardware problem. I suspect the issue is that when Windows goes back into a user-not-idle state, the maintenance task doesn't stop or just takes way too long to stop.

Comment: When Automatic Maintenance is ran on any of my machines I use what you describe does not happen.  I guarantee you my laptop is a several factors slower then your computer.

Comment: Fairly normal, in my experience.  Best thing is to schedule the maintenance for 3AM.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, I've already got it scheduled for something like that. The disruptive maintenance I'm describing occurs during waking hours. I think it's the "User is idle" type of maintenance.

Comment: It does RAM checks, compiles .Net files into native code and removes files from WinSxS. disable it when you don't want this: http://superuser.com/a/502049/174557